# How to conditionally apply styles in a react component with CSS Modules?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, css-modules

I'm using *CSS Modules* to scope all my styles locally by default. From my understanding the only way I'm able to use the class names set in the local stylesheet (`./movieCard.styl`), is by using the attribute `styleName="something"`. So `className="something"`, won't be able to access styles in `./movieCard.styl`. I guess I could use the `style={}` method on the HTML element, but I want my components clean with no style markup - so I'm hoping there is another way of doing it with the way CSS Module syntax behave.

I have tried the following (Even though the methods don't give any errors, they don't work):
`styleName={isHovered ? ' movie-card--show' : ''}`
`className={isHovered ? ' movie-card--show' : ''}`

*Context: I'm trying to show the movie information based on if the user is hovering over the movie poster or not. I will need to apply some sort of styling to the `move-card__info` element to make the text visible when the poster is hovered.*

Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CSSModule from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './movieCard.styl';

class MovieCard extends Component {
  state = {
    movie: this.props.movie,
    isHovered: false,
  };

  cardHoverToggle = () => {
    const { isHovered } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isHovered: !isHovered });
  };

  render() {
    const { movie, isHovered } = this.state;

    return (
      <div styleName="movie-card" onMouseEnter={this.cardHoverToggle} onMouseLeave={this.cardHoverToggle}>
        <img
          styleName="movie-card__poster"
          src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/${movie.poster_path}`}
          alt={`Movie poster for ${movie.original_title}`}
        />

        <div styleName="movie-card__info">
          <p>{movie.original_title}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CSSModule(MovieCard, styles);
```

**Question:** How would I be able to conditionally apply styles written in the local scope of the react-component (*CSS Module*), based on a *state*? Is this possible to do with `styleName`, if so how?

Comment: [Looks like there is no way to do this](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/215), but I'm not sure. Do you have the option of using "regular" CSS modules with just Webpack? Then you can do `className={isHovered ? styles.myCardShow : ''}` like you alluded to in your question.

Comment: using a higher order component to inject props might work. Can you create a sandbox/codepen so that we can try out approaches ?

Answer (score 18):

I have no experience with `styleName` but this is how I achieve this with `className`:

```
const completedClass = task.completed ? styles.isCompleted : '';

return (
    <div className={`${styles.task} ${completedClass}`}>
    </div>
)
```

So if `completedClass` is true `styles.isCompleted` will be added to `className` alongside `styles.task` which doesn't care about the state.

I have used string literals as I need multiple classes, if `styles.isCompleted` was the only class I needed I could use:

```
className={completedClass}
```

or

```
className={task.completed ? styles.isCompleted : ''}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another type of spelling

```
import cx from 'classnames';
import s from './style.scss';
```

Render part

```
<div className={cx(s.container, {
    [s.hovered]: this.state.isHovered,
})}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to add 'movie-card--show' on current className you can use it with classnames.

`import classnames from 'classnames';`

Usage:

```
className={classnames('Here-goes-your-classes-you-always-use', { 'movie-card--show': isHovered })}
```

if isHovered is true it will add another class to your 'Always use classes'

Example:

Lets say you have a simple div

```
<div className={classnames('container',{'new-style' : isHovered})}>
```

if `isHovered = true` className whould look like

```
className="container new-style"
```

if `isHovered = false`

```
className="container"
```

Answer (score 0):

And also You can write like this

```
import classnames from "classnames";
import classes from "./Navbar.module.scss";
```

and within the div or element

```
className={[classnames(classes.navbar, {
          [classes.navbar__hidden]: !this.state.visible
        })].join(" ")}
```